# Why shutdown command does not work in Task Scheduler in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-task-scheduler

I've added a `shutdown /h /t 120` to the Task Scheduler in Windows 7. I've set it to be run only if my administrator user is logged in and with highest privileges. But it does not work.

When I fire the command from **cmd** it does not work. I am able to hibernate from Start menu.

Shutdown /s on the other hand works from cmd and from Task Scheduler.

How to hibernate windows 7 properly from Task Scheduler?

Answer (score 2):

*shutdown.exe* does not allow the `/t` parameter to be used along with either `/l` (log off) or `/h` (hibernate) for some reason.

You can make the task execute `shutdown /h` (i.e. without `/t`) to hibernate. If you want a window wherein you can cancel the scheduled hibernation (using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>), make the task execute *cmd.exe* instead with the following arguments:

```
/c "timeout /t 120 /nobreak && shutdown /h"
```

[image: 1]

Remember to use **&&** and not **&**, or else the second command (`shutdown /h` in this case) will run irrespective of whether the first one (`timeout /t 120 /nobreak`) was cancelled or not.

Answer (score 0):

In Task Scheduler, "Actions" field, write the following command to launch hibernate:

rundll32.exe PowrProf.dll,SetSuspendState

Of course, make sure Hibernate is enabled on your PC.